# Approaching OOP in Lua

Tags: class, object, oop, lua, metatable

this is the first time I try to apply OOP in Lua. This class is a derivative of the "Frame" class already present in the game

```
LibListView = {}

function LibListView:New(self)
    local listviewmt = {
            buttons  = {}, 
            data = {},
            initiated = true,
        
            OldSetScript = SetScript,
            SetScript = nil,
            -- more parameters and methods
            SetScript = function(self,handler,fnctn)
                local scripts = "OnHide,OnLoad,OnMouseWheel,OnSizeChanged,OnShow,OnUpdate"
                if string.find(scripts,handler) then
                    self:HookScript(handler,fnctn)
                else
                    self.OldSetScript(handler,fnctn)
                end
            end,
        }
        setmetatable(self, { __index = setmetatable(listviewmt, getmetatable(self)) })
        -- not simply setmetatable(main, class) to avoid already present meta overwritting
end
```

If I write

```
listview = LibListView:New(self)
```

the code works fine. At this point, I would like to make sure that the class is created without passing `self` as a parameter: in short, using the wording

```
listview = LibListView:New()
```

to make the code more elegant.

Some advice?

Comment: Are you sure the code works fine? AFAIC `self` is undefined, so `getmetatable(self)` should report an error. Additionally the `New` function returns nothing, so listview is nil. Besides I don't understand the purpose of the setmetatable line, Do the 2 self refer to the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

This defines `self` twice `function LibListView:New(self)` when you make a method using `:` instead of `.` the first param is hidden and named `self`. What you did here is made the second param also called `self`.

you have 2 options,

1. do not put `self` in the signature just leave it without any params: `function LibListView:New()`, you will still have access to the param `self` within the method.
2. do not use `:` and define the first param as `self`:  `function LibListView.New(self)`, you can still call this using the `:` sugar syntax.

Here is a resource for learning more about how `:` works in lua: [Programming in Lua: Chapter 16 – Object-Oriented Programming](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html)

This is a particularly relevant quote from the  chapter:

> This use of a self parameter is a central point in any object-oriented language. Most OO languages have this mechanism partly hidden from the programmer, so that she does not have to declare this parameter (although she still can use the name self or this inside a method). Lua can also hide this parameter, using the colon operator. We can rewrite the previous method definition as
>
> ```
>    function Account:withdraw (v)
>      self.balance = self.balance - v
>    end
> ```